# Grids not originating from 2D parameter spaces

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, grids-graticules

Is there any specific name for grids on sphere (or geoid, or any other manifold/surface) that do not originate from 2D parameter space?

For example generating a grid on a sphere using icosahedron tessellation do not involve any 2D parameters.

I'd like to read more about such grids. Any recommendations on literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wiki/Tessellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation)

> A **tessellation** of a flat surface is the tiling of a plane using one or more geometric shapes, called tiles, with no overlaps and no gaps.

I think the same word can be used to describe the tiling of a sphere.

If you're after the (very conventional) spherical equivalent of a planar grid, then the word is **graticule** – the pattern formed by a series of intersecting  meridians of longitude and parallels of latitude.

See also [wiki/Grid_spatial_index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_%28spatial_index%29):

> In the context of a spatial index, a grid (a.k.a. "mesh", also "global
>   grid" if it covers the entire surface of the globe) is a regular
>   tessellation of a manifold or 2-D surface that divides it into a
>   series of contiguous cells, which can then be assigned unique
>   identifiers and used for spatial indexing purposes. A wide variety of
>   such grids have been proposed or are currently in use, including grids
>   based on "square" or "rectangular" cells, triangular grids or meshes,
>   hexagonal grids and grids based on diamond-shaped cells.